# GECODE Pairwise Distinct Columns In A Matrix

Tags: c++, gecode

I'm working on a GECODE solver to implement a Matrix Generation problem. I have figured out all the constraints I require except for one:

`Given a Matrix[M, N], all column vectors must be pairwise distinct.`

This is the code I would like to write:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
        if( i != j )
        {
          notsame(*this, m.col(i), m.col(j));
        }
      }
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to express that with the provided primitive constraints. I know `distinct()` exists, however I can't figure out how to operate over columns in a matrix, instead of elements in the column matrix itself. What would be the best way to express this constraint over matricies?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with an implementation that seems to work.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
      {
        if( i != j )
        {
          // Every column should not be equal to any other column
          // Check each column pairwise element
          BoolVarArgs equalities;
          for(int r = 0; r < M; r++)
          {
            equalities << expr(*this, m(i, r) == m(j, r));  
          }
          rel(*this, BOT_AND, equalities, 0);
        }
      }
    }
```